# Problema com a propriedade font

Tags: css

Estou utilizando várias propriedades em uma só.
Por exemplo, ao invés de eu usar `font-family`, `font-size`, estou usando apenas `font`, conforme abaixo:

```
.topoMenu li{
    font: 20px 'Ubuntu', sans-serif, #000, 300;
}
```

O último é o `font-weigth`, só que quando eu informo ele, dá problema, não formata a fonte corretamente, se eu tirar funciona de boa.

É problema com a sintaxe?

Comment: Sou sincero, só se fosse um grande expert em css é que fazia isso que estás a fazer. Para além de se tornar mais confuso, convém antes fazer um pequeno estudo/testes e ver estudar sintaxe corretamente, que deve ser o teu problema.

Comment: Encontrei este link, dá uma vista de olhos: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font/

Comment: Qual fonte está a usar? É alguma que os sistemas não costumam ter localmente?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De acordo com [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font)

> The order of the values is not completely free: font-style, font-variant and font-weight must be defined, if any, before the font-size value. The line-height value must be defined immediately after the font-size, preceded by a mandatory /. Finally the font-family is mandatory and must be the last value defined (inherit value does not work).

Você precisa definir `font-style`, `font-variant` e `font-weight` antes do `font-size`. `Font-family` é mandatório e deve ser o último valor.

Não é possível definer a cor no font shorthand.

**Sintaxe:**

> Formal syntax: [ [ <‘font-style’> ||  || <‘font-weight’> || <‘font-stretch’> ]? <‘font-size’> [ / <‘line-height’> ]? <‘font-family’> ] | caption | icon | menu | message-box | small-caption | status-bar

Utilize `color`. O seguinte trecho deve funcionar.

```
.topoMenu li{
    font: 300 20px 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: #000;
}
```

[image: Cheat sheet]

Comment: Esse tipo de formação roda bem nas versões do IE?

Comment: sim. sem problemas. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font#Browser_Compatibility

Answer (score 5):

Existe uma ordem a ser seguida: *font-style, font-variant, font-weight, font-size, line-height, e font-family.*, pois a propriedade `font` nada mais é do que um atalho para setar essas propriedades numa propriedade só, e como você pode reparar a propriedade color não existe no `font` também.

```css
.topoMenu li{
    font: 300 20px 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<ul class="topoMenu">
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Leia mais [aqui](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/font) (W3C)